# 1054 error in mysql because of trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-error-1054

```
-- Table `testas`.`groups`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `testas`.`groups` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `testas`.`groups` (
  `ID` VARCHAR(36) NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `count` INT(10) NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` VARCHAR(36) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`count`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

This is my code for a table creation and I have a trigger BEFORE DELETE that has to set parent_id to 0 if id of deleted record matches with parent_id.

Here's code of the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `groups_BEFORE_DELETE` BEFORE DELETE ON `groups`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF OLD.ID = parent_id THEN
        INSERT INTO groups(parent_id) values ('0');
    END IF;
END
```

I get an error when I want to delete one of the records.

> #1054 - unknown column 'parent_id' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
INSERT INTO groups(parent_id) values ('0');
```

I think you meant

```
SET NEW.parent_id := 0;
```